# How to pass FetchedResults as Binding

Tags: core-data, swiftui

How to map and pass `FetchedResults<CDItem>` as `Binding` to inner view which is UIKit wrapper to avoid recreating inner view on outside changes?

Simple sample:

```
struct CollectionView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding 
    var items: [Item] // array of structs which are core data entities representation

    ...
}

struct ItemsView: View {
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: CDItem.fetchReuqest)
    var items: FetchedResults<CDItem>

    var body: some View {
        CollectionView(items: /* ??? */)
    }
}
```

First idea I had - make some `ObservableObject` with `NSFetchedResultsController` inside and update some `@Published` variable with `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and then use easy way to convert it to Binding. But I would like to use such sugar as `@FetchRequest`

Comment: CoreData items are not `struct`. Creating a two-way connection (Binding) with `@FetchRequest` has no purpose since it isn't writeable. If you elaborate on your use case we might be able to help you better.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` is also not writeable so an `@Binding` isn't needed either. Both `@FetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController` are always listening to the store. Any changes will be reflected automatically when the store is updated.

Comment: `NSFetchRequest` doesn't listen. So Views won't be automatically redrawn when you change the objects.

Comment: @loremipsum Hello! Thank you for participating! I want to use `UICollectionView` with `UICompositionLayout` inside `SwiftUI` (using `UIViewRepresentable`) with data coming from `CoreData` inside `SwiftUI`. I need `UICollectionView` because paging and drag & drop work well here

Comment: What you are using it for doesn't affect my comments. `@Binding` is by definition a two-way connection `@FetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController` are not two-way. You have to affect the store to see any changes. You can pass an array of objects, just for reading, a `let` property does the trick.

Comment: Oh... Seems you are totally right! Thank you! You can create answer, and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Binding` is by definition a two-way connection `@FetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController` are not two-way.

If you need to pass around `items` from the store use

```
let items: [CDItem]
```

or

```
let items: [Item]
```

If you are abstracting.

The only way to affect `@FetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController` is to make changes to the store. They are always listening.